# Delegate equivalent of Obj-C in Java

Tags: java, objective-c, delegates

In Objective-C, for creating and handling a connection (NSURLConnection), it has a delegate, with methods like didConnect, didFailWithError etc, which are called as required. This is good and simple.
How does Java handle connection events (or similar things)? Something listener pattern is there, do one has to register for everything to listen? Something automatic callback?

Comment: Note that "delegates" are not a "feature" of Objective-C, but rather are just a "pattern" frequently used by Cocoa (and many user) APIs.  Absolutely nothing special about the way a "delegate" is supported vs any other class.

Comment: Hot Licks is right as usual: delegation is just a design pattern. You can use essentially the same pattern in any code, in any language: some chunk of code asks another chunk of code whether it should do something. Are you really asking about delegation _in general_, or about finding equivalent functionality to `NSURLConnection` in a Java framework?

Comment: In this context the only difference is that there are abstract classes and interfaces instead of protocols.

Answer (score 6):

In Java, the equivalent mechanism would be that of EventListeners and EventHandlers. The GUI classes are full of examples of their usage. And there's nothing "automatic" about them, you need to explicitly register handlers for the events of interest.

Comment: +1 Some frameworks support automagically registering listeners.

Answer (score 0):

There's no direct equivalent of the delegation pattern as intended in Objective-C.

You can achieve pretty much the same results by using the publish-subscribe pattern, implemented in Objective-C by the `NSNotificationCenter` and in Java by `EventListeners` and `EventHandlers`.

Answer (score 0):

After all a delegate is just a class that is guaranteed to have some methods so that you can call them, to let it handle some evenets.

So just declare an interface or abstract class with all the methods that you want to be there like didConnect, etc... then the class holding the delegate will just call these methods, and it will be sure that they will be there.